# Is there a way to disable ssl validation in Visual studio Team Explorer window?

Tags: git, ssl, visual-studio-2015

I used Team Explorer to connect to Gitlab server which is using self-signed certificate.
But Team Explorer won't allow me to do anything even though I have set http.sslverify to false.

In this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/10/20/git-network-operations-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) he said that "If an HTTPS URI is used for a remote, the Windows certificate store is used to validate the server’s SSL certificate."

Is there the way to disable this ssl validation?

The certificate is trusted but it's still invalid because of url mismatch and I can't do anything with theirs certificate.

[image: error]

Answer (score 6):

Since SSL verification is a "git" thing, and Visual Studio Git extension is just a wrapper over it, you can set the git option to ignore checking ssl. Just open a command prompt and do the following:

```
cd c:\path\to\project\folder
git config http.sslVerify false
```

Then go back to visual studio and everything goes fine.

If you want this to work for all of your git projects, add "--global" option to the git command.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/34301/self-signed-ssl-certificate-use-during-debug-dont.html), I tried moving the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store and that worked for me.
If URL mismatch is the issue, another workaround could be to create a `hosts` entry with the matching url as the alias.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you can't turn off SSL validation, since Visual Studio handles the http connections and if I'm not mistaking it handles the setup and security for LibGit2 under the hood, but you can add an item in the Hosts file with the name expected by the certificate. That generally does the trick.

A better solution would be to just fix the SSL certificate, especially if it's self-signed, there should be no cost involved to ensure it has the right domain names.